# Ошибка telebot.anihelper.ApiException

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, telebot

Есть бот для телеграмма, который парсит стену с группы ВК и отправляет её в телеграм канал.

При попытке запустить, стену он парсит успешно, но отправить в канал — не может.

```
⁠⁠Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 208, in <module>
check_posts_vk()
File "main.py", line 126, in check_posts_vk
bot.send_message(CHANNEL, text + '[⁠](' + image_url + ')', parse_mode='Markdown')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Еррорящий код:

```py
    if len(images) > 0:
        image_url = str(max(img["sizes"], key=lambda size: size["type"])["url"])

        bot.send_message(CHANNEL, text + '[⁠](' + image_url + ')', parse_mode='Markdown')
        # между квадратными скобками стоит world joiner. М.б. из-за него еррорит?
```

Помогите, плиз

Comment: `между квадратными скобками стоит world joiner`, действительно там что-то есть `>>> len('[⁠]')  3` :)

Comment: Попробуйте до `bot.send_message(` просто вывести `msg = text + '[⁠](' + image_url + ')'` `print(msg)`, скорее всего проблема в строке с конкатенацией, но непонятно почему у вас как ASCII текст. В начале файла есть строка `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`? Если нет, то добавьте

Comment: Спасибо, я уже обычным HTML себя спас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто используй HTML

```
mention= f'<a href="{image_url}">{text}</a>'
bot.send_message(CHANNEL, mention, parse_mode="HTML")
```

Comment: До меня уже дошло, но всё равно, спасибо :)